# Issue with Drupal "sites" folder

Tags: drupal, themes

I have a Drupal install on the MediaTemple gs hosting plan. The site is up and working fine but I've had some issues with the "sites" folder.

If I put themes in the "sites/default/themes" folder, they show up on the "Themes" folder but none of the icons show up for each theme. Enabling a theme removes all the styling from the site like it can't get to the CSS. Moving the themes from "sites/default/themes" to "/themes" fixed the problem but I don't think this is the best way to handle it.

I've checked my permissions and they seem good - am I missing something here?

Comment: Trying to link directly to the screenshot of a theme gives me a 403 access error. Checking my logs shows that it's trying to find my non-existent .htaccess file.

Answer (score 2):

Doh! Permissions was the issue. I forgot to enable "execute" for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

The proper place for themes is as follows.

Themes included in the core Drupal distribution:

`themes`

Themes downloaded from the web, but not included with core:

`sites/all/themes/contrib`

or

`sites/example.com/themes/contrib`

Themes you wrote yourself:

`sites/all/themes/custom`

or

`sites/example.com/themes/contrib`

You would use the locations with example.com in the path if you are using Drupal's multisite capability to run multiple Drupal sites on a single codebase. (Things under `sites/all` are available to all sites; things under `sites/example.com` are available only to the example.com site.)